# Changing macbook air hotkeys to default operation

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macbook-air

I have a macbook air which I use for web development. I have recently shifted to a mac and have been facing problems with the keyboard layout.

I want to enable the default behaviour of the function keys so that I don't have to press the "fn" key everytime I want to step into the code using F10.

Basically what I want is - swap the functionality of Fn + F10 with F10. This needs to be done for all function keys.

Ultimately if I want to increase the volume I should press the Fn+F12 key instead of the default f12 key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Use all F1 F2 etc keys as functional keys.`

You can read more [here.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3399?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)